# get youtube video without authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube-api

How can you make youtube requests without a developer key?

eg i have:

```
Uri videoEntryUrl = new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/xyz123");
Video video = request.Retrieve<Video>(videoEntryUrl);
```

i want the video object, but the request object requires credentials etc - is there a way round this?

The [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html) does say:

> Read-only requests to retrieve public videos do not require
>   authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise your `YouTubeRequestSettings` with nulls:

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(null, null);
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
Uri videoEntryUrl = new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/xyz123");
Video video = request.Retrieve<Video>(videoEntryUrl);
```